# Python Pandas gather all occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas so I am not sure if i am doing what i want the best way possible, and one part seems to not be working properly.

In my database I have a table that records all the sells of the products on my website and I would like to create a csv report with all the product that have been sold, min price, max, price, and other information. The table that sells each sale has the following attributes:

```
product_id
sell_price
created_by
```

From my research i found out how to make a dataframe with the csv from a db export for now like below.

```
sellsdb = pd.read_csv('sellsdb.csv', delimiter = ',')
```

Now I make a copy of that dataframe without duplicates.

```
sells = sellsdb.copy().drop_duplicates(subset='product_id', keep=False)
```

Now I loop over each unique product title in the copied dataframe

```
for index, row in sells.iterrows():
    countSells = sellsdb.loc[sellsdb['product_id'] == str(row['product_id'])].count()['product_id']
    if countSells > 1:
        print(countSells)
```

When I run this i have all the counts comming back as 1 even when there is a duplicate in the dataframe, but when I hard code a product id i get the right number for that id. What is going on?

In the loop i was just going to append the columns that i need for the report to the dataframe of no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your DataFrame contains:

```
  product_id  sell_price created_by
0        Aaa       20.35      Xxxx1
1        Aaa       20.15      Xxxx2
2        Aaa       22.00      Xxxx3
3        Bbb       10.13      Xxxx4
4        Ccc       16.00      Xxxx5
5        Ccc       16.50      Xxxx6
6        Ccc       17.00      Xxxx7
```

To compute the number of sales per product it is much easier (and more
*pandasonic*) to run:

```
result = df.groupby('product_id').sell_price.count().rename('cnt')
```

I added *rename('cnt')* to give the result a meaningful name.
Otherwise the name would have been inherited from the original column
(*sell_price*), but the values are numbers of sales, not prices.

The result, for the above sample input, is:

```
product_id
Aaa    3
Bbb    1
Ccc    3
Name: cnt, dtype: int64
```

It is a *Series* with index named *product_id* and the value under each
index is the count of sales of this product.

And the final remark: I named the result *cnt* (not *count*) because
*count* is the name of a *Pandas* function (used here) and it is a bad
practice to use names "overwriting" names of existing functions or
attributes.